String_Agg concatenating duplicated value when there is multiple Ids exist
Table
Claim_Id    Service_Id  Service_Line_Id     col  
------------------------------------------------
1599316     H2012       1653805             
1599316     H2012       1653805             HE
1599316     H2012       1653805             TG

1599316     H2012       1653806 
1599316     H2012       1653806             HE
1599316     H2012       1653806             TG

I'm trying to concatenate the values  to become grouped by servicelineId, but it's appearing like this:
claim_id    Service_Line_Id concatenatedvalue   Service_Id  procedure_modifier1 procedure_modifier2 procedure_modifier3 procedure_modifier4
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1599316     1653805         H2012HEHETGTG       H2012           HE                      TG                                      
1599316     1653806         H2012HEHETGTG       H2012           HE                      TG                                      

But expected result in concatenatedvalue H2012HETG like will be like
claim_id    Service_Line_Id concatenatedvalue   Service_Id  procedure_modifier1 procedure_modifier2 procedure_modifier3 procedure_modifier4
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1599316     1653805         H2012HETG           H2012           HE                      TG                                      
1599316     1653806         H2012HETG           H2012           HE                      TG

                                    

I'm using the like below query to achieve the results, looks I'm missing the group logic in area
CONCAT(unioncte.Service_Id, STRING_AGG(col, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col)) AS  concatenatedvalue


SELECT
    unioncte.claim_id,
    CONCAT(unioncte.Service_Id, STRING_AGG(col, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col)) AS concatenatedvalue,
    unioncte.Service_Id   
FROM 
    unioncte        
GROUP BY  
    unioncte.Claim_Id, unioncte.Service_Id, 
    procedure_modifier1, procedure_modifier2, 
    procedure_modifier3, procedure_modifier4


A step seems to be missing. Please show how you get these columns:  procedure_modifier1 procedure_modifier2 procedure_modifier3 procedure_modifier4

That code looks familiar  ;) You may need to dedup your data up in your cte where you unpivot, OR dedup after you unpivot, but before you string_agg. If you share some raw (pre-unpivoted) sample data that is leading to this scenario it might help.

You might have a one-to-many join issue. Consider using the alternative answer to your other question and see if that resolves the issue. It's tough to say what's wrong without seeing your entire query.

You need Service_Line_Id in the GROUP BY clause. You can also simplify the STRING_AGG call.
SELECT
    claim_id,
    Service_Line_Id,
    CONCAT(Service_Id, STRING_AGG(col, '')) AS concatenatedvalue,
    Service_Id   
FROM 
    unioncte        
GROUP BY  
    Claim_Id, Service_Line_Id,Service_Id

fiddle



claim_id
Service_Line_Id
concatenatedvalue
Service_Id




1599316
1653805
H2012HETG
H2012


1599316
1653806
H2012HETG
H2012



